# Why can't I assign random.nextInt to a variable?

Tags: java, variables, random, assign

I want the variables p and z to get a new random number assigned to them but I get a NullPointerException when using the code below. I've done something similar before and it worked fine so I am probably being silly and missing something obvious. Any help? Thanks!

example code:

```
private int p;
private int z;
private Random rand;

public test()
{
    p = 0;
    z = 0;
}

public void print()
{
    p = rand.nextInt(9);
    z = rand.nextInt(9);
    System.out.println(p + " " + z);
}
```

Comment: Because you haven't initialized `rand`.  `rand = new Random(666);`.

Comment: @WonkotheSane But that's not really relevant here (plus [instance variables have known default values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Answer (score 8):

You haven't initialized `rand` to anything yet, so Java initializes it to `null`, per [JLS 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).  Try

```
private Random rand = new Random();
```

Comment: Wow, so stupid of me! Thanks for the quick reply :)